# Escanear red para encontrar las IP

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una práctica donde me piden hacer un Escaneado de red local y que en Datagridview muestre todas las IP tantos las activas y las inactivas, he buscado como hacerlo pero no les entiendo.

[image: Ya tengo lo que es IP del equipo, la Mascara de Subred y la MAC]

Pero me falta tener cual es la red en la que esta conectado el equipo y escanear la red todas sus ip y mostrarlo en un datagridview.

[image: Si selecciono por rango de IP va aparecer las cajas de texto para escribir la IP que desea ver y si es por la red actual va escanear todas las IP]

Este es el código que tengo en una clase llamada DeviceInfo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace RedMonIpScanner
{


    public static class SubnetMask
    {
        public static readonly IPAddress ClassA = IPAddress.Parse("255.0.0.0");
        public static readonly IPAddress ClassB = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.0.0");
        public static readonly IPAddress ClassC = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");

        public static IPAddress CreateByHostBitLength(int hostpartLength)
        {
            int hostPartLength = hostpartLength;
            int netPartLength = 32 - hostPartLength;

            if (netPartLength < 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("Number of hosts is to large for IPv4");

            Byte[] binaryMask = new byte[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (i * 8 + 8 <= netPartLength)
                    binaryMask[i] = (byte)255;
                else if (i * 8 > netPartLength)
                    binaryMask[i] = (byte)0;
                else
                {
                    int oneLength = netPartLength - i * 8;
                    string binaryDigit =
                        String.Empty.PadLeft(oneLength, '1').PadRight(8, '0');
                    binaryMask[i] = Convert.ToByte(binaryDigit, 2);
                }
            }
            return new IPAddress(binaryMask);
        }

        public static IPAddress CreateByNetBitLength(int netpartLength)
        {
            int hostPartLength = 32 - netpartLength;
            return CreateByHostBitLength(hostPartLength);
        }

        public static IPAddress CreateByHostNumber(int numberOfHosts)
        {
            int maxNumber = numberOfHosts + 1;

            string b = Convert.ToString(maxNumber, 2);

            return CreateByHostBitLength(b.Length);
        }
    }

    public static class IPAddressExtensions
    {
        public static IPAddress GetBroadcastAddress(this IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask)
        {
            byte[] ipAdressBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
            byte[] subnetMaskBytes = subnetMask.GetAddressBytes();

            if (ipAdressBytes.Length != subnetMaskBytes.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException("Lengths of IP address and subnet mask do not match.");

            byte[] broadcastAddress = new byte[ipAdressBytes.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < broadcastAddress.Length; i++)
            {
                broadcastAddress[i] = (byte)(ipAdressBytes[i] | (subnetMaskBytes[i] ^ 255));
            }
            return new IPAddress(broadcastAddress);
        }

        public static IPAddress GetNetworkAddress(this IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask)
        {
            byte[] ipAdressBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
            byte[] subnetMaskBytes = subnetMask.GetAddressBytes();

            if (ipAdressBytes.Length != subnetMaskBytes.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException("Lengths of IP address and subnet mask do not match.");

            byte[] broadcastAddress = new byte[ipAdressBytes.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < broadcastAddress.Length; i++)
            {
                broadcastAddress[i] = (byte)(ipAdressBytes[i] & (subnetMaskBytes[i]));
            }
            return new IPAddress(broadcastAddress);
        }

        public static bool IsInSameSubnet(this IPAddress address2, IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask)
        {
            IPAddress network1 = address.GetNetworkAddress(subnetMask);
            IPAddress network2 = address2.GetNetworkAddress(subnetMask);

            return network1.Equals(network2);
        }

    }
    public class DeviceInfo
    { 
    public static ArrayList GetMacAddress()
    {
        // Contador para un ciclo
        int i = 0;
        // Colección de direcciones MAC
        ArrayList DireccionesMAC = new ArrayList();
        // Información de las tarjetas de red
        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = null;
        // Obtener todas las interfaces de red de la PC
        interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        // Validar la cantidad de tarjetas de red que tiene
        if (interfaces != null && interfaces.Length > 0)
        {
            // Recorrer todas las interfaces de red
            foreach (NetworkInterface adaptador in interfaces)
            {
                // Obtener la dirección fisica
                PhysicalAddress direccion = adaptador.GetPhysicalAddress();
                // Obtener en modo de arreglo de bytes la dirección
                byte[] bytes = direccion.GetAddressBytes();
                // Variable que tendra la dirección visible
                string mac_address = string.Empty;
                // Recorrer todos los bytes de la direccion
                for (i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    // Pasar el byte a un formato legible para el usuario
                    mac_address += bytes[i].ToString("X2");
                    if (i != bytes.Length - 1)
                    {
                        // Agregar un separador, por formato
                        mac_address += "-";
                    }
                }
                // Agregar la direccion MAC a la lista
                DireccionesMAC.Add(mac_address);
            }
        }
        // Valor de retorno, la lista de direcciones MAC
        return DireccionesMAC;
    }
    }
}
```

Y este es el código que tengo en mi form1 donde mando a llamar las funciones de mi clase:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; //Para tener alcance a la Clase Ping
using System.IO; //Para el manejo de archivos
namespace RedMonIpScanner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            string myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList.Where(a => a.IsIPv6LinkLocal == false).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            string submask = SubnetMask.CreateByHostBitLength(myIP.Length).ToString();


            lblip.Text = myIP;
            lblmac.Text = DeviceInfo.GetMacAddress()[0].ToString();
            lblmask.Text = submask;
        }

        private void Btnescanear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            Object selectedItem = ComboBox1.SelectedItem;

            if (selectedIndex.ToString() == "0" ){

                lblseparador.Visible = true;
                txtipini.Visible = true;
                txtipfin.Visible = true;
               }               

               else if (selectedIndex.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    lblseparador.Visible = false ;
                    txtipini.Visible = false ;
                    txtipfin.Visible = false ;
                }



            //MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem.ToString() + "\n" +
                            //"Index: " + selectedIndex.ToString());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa cómo funciona la herramienta de scaneo "nmap", te dará mejores ideas de networ scanning